# Vertx unnamed prepared statement does not exist(PgBouncer)

Tags: postgresql, vert.x, pgbouncer

When I attept to execute any request(through pg bouncer), then get exception
Caused by: io.vertx.pgclient.PgException: { "message": "unnamed prepared statement does not exist", "severity": "ERROR", "code": "26000", "file": "postgres.c", "line": "1620", "routine": "exec_bind_message" }

But if I exec directly to postgres(not through), everything OK

Comment: 1) All properties like cachePreparedStatements are false
2) addProperty("prepareThreshold", "0") doesnt work

Comment: This isn't directly related to Vert.x, but to your PgBouncer config: https://blog.bullgare.com/2019/06/pgbouncer-and-prepared-statements/

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Yes, you are right , I need turn on Session mode on bouncer...Thx!